# Trying to redirect to url path raises Werkzeug BuildError

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

After logging in successfully I want to redirect to `/metering`.  However, a `werkzeug.routing.BuildError` is raised after sucessful login.  Why am I getting this error?

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  error=None
  if request.method=='POST':
    if request.form['username']!='admin' or request.form['password']!='1234':
      error ='Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    else:
      return redirect(url_for('/metering'))
  return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/metering')
def hello1():
    return render_template('metering.html')
```

Comment: What exactly happens in your current solution?

Comment: @fast  I don't need this, but need httpbasicauth token based authentication, I follow the tutorial but didn't get..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because `url_for` expects an endpoing name, not a url (it *builds* the url).  You've named your function `hello1`, so that is the default name of the endpoint associated with the path `/metering`.  Pass `'hello'` to `url_for`.

```
return redirect(url_for('hello1'))
```